# What is the difference between a CSS and XPath selector? And which is better with respect to performance for cross-browser testing?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am working with the [Selenium WebDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)#Selenium_WebDriver) 2.25.0 on a multilingual web application and mainly test the page content (for different languages, like Arabic, English, Russian, and so on).

For my application, which is better according to performance and make sure that it should be supported for all the browsers (i.e., [Internet Explorer 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_7), [8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8), [9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9), Firefox, Chrome, etc.)?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

CSS selectors perform far better than XPath selectors, and it is well documented in Selenium community. Here are some reasons:

- XPath engines are different in each browser, hence making them inconsistent
- Internet Explorer does not have a native XPath engine, and therefore Selenium injects its own XPath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the advantage of using native browser features that WebDriver inherently promotes.
- XPath expressions tend to become complex and hence make them hard to read in my opinion

However, there are some situations where you need to use an XPath selector, for example, searching for a parent element or searching element by its text (I wouldn't recommend the latter).

You can read blog from Simon [here](https://conference.eurostarsoftwaretesting.com/liveblogged-automated-web-testing-traps-unwary-simon-stewart/). He also recommends CSS over XPath.

If you are testing content, then do not use selectors that are dependent on the content of the elements. That will be a maintenance nightmare for every locale. Try talking with developers and use techniques that they used to externalize the text in the application, like dictionaries or resource bundles, etc. Here is [my blog post](http://nileshdk.wordpress.com/2013/08/06/internationalization-automating-localized-ui-using-selenium-webdriver/) that explains it in detail.

[Thanks to parishodak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-a-css-and-xpath-selector-and-which-is-better-wit/16794683#comment56717007_16794683), here is [the link](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2) which provides the numbers proving that CSS performance is better.

Comment: Thanks for reply, right now we are using the excel file for store the page content & compare excel content with the page content. this can be done with the Xpath. If i like to replace all Xpath by CSS-selector, it gives the advantage or not?

Comment: CSS selectors do not allow text. 'contains' is deprecated in CSS. Like I said above, have selectors independent of the content. Content can reside outside. You can talk to developers. They must have externalized the text. They most of the times have dictionaries per locale. So the keys in the dictionaries are same but the values change as per the locale. You can use these files to validate the content. Note that you need to convert native characters into ascii characters using nativ2ascii tool from JDK. I must write a blog on this. I did test many locales using this technique.

Comment: Nilesh, i got some idea but no full(some doubts are remains), please send me your blog link. so, i will to take follow up.

Comment: @Chetanचेतन I added my blog link in the answer. Sorry it took a while. Hopefully that will help you.

Comment: @Nilesh: I do not agree with your answer. 1.) CSS engines are also different in each browser. This is not an argument. 3.) With some experience XPath is very easy to understand and offers more functionality than CSS. If you search for a very nested element they are both complex: XPath and CSS. In my experience any general answer to this question will be wrong. The decision CSS/XPATH must be taken individually. The original question was about performance. Your answer mainly consists of assumptions and personal opinions. A real prove would be to MEASURE the performance and post the results here.

Comment: @Elmue, this [link](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2) will provide the numbers proving that CSS performance is better

Comment: Thanks @parishodak, link has been added to the answer as an edit

Comment: A very good article which contradicts your first sentence: "CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath". It is not that simple, it may even be the opposite. And: "IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium injects its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API." Here Selenium suffers from a design error. It would surely have been better to implement the XPath engine in C++ instead of java script. But IE is dead, now comes Edge. Behind all performance questions one must not forget that CSS lacks very important functionality like searching for the text of an element.

Comment: Article doesn't contradict my first sentence entirely, on the other hand it does support it. Also talking about selenium design flaw is totally out of scope from this discussion. In addition, I never say don't use xpath, in fact I provided examples where xpath is a must.

Comment: based on my investigation:
a. Simple website with unique css/id to get elements: Use css or id
b. Complex html generated by e.g ExtJS: go by relative xpath or js query (e.g using ext js component query)

In a complex html, css/id is not preferred because
a. css boils down to multiple nodes
b. ids are each time dynamically generated (e.g website based on extjs)

Comment: Complex html should not exist. Testability should win and developers should provide you those hooks or unique attributes

Comment: Selenium provides enough helper methods to find elements by various strategies. The simplification of testing should happen here. 
Yes, there are instances when front-end developer can add markers for testability. However, asking front-end developers to add unnecessary markers in html  (just) for testing, pollutes the front-end js code

Comment: http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css provides benchmarks that suggest css3 is no longer significantly faster.

Answer (score 66):

I’m going to hold the unpopular on SO Selenium tag opinion that an **XPath selector is preferable** to a CSS selector in the long run.

This long post has two sections - first I'll put a back-of-the-napkin proof the performance difference between the two is **0.1-0.3 milliseconds** *(yes; that's 100 **micro**seconds)*, and then I'll share my opinion why XPath is more powerful.

---

## Performance difference

Let's first tackle "the elephant in the room" – that XPath is slower than CSS.

With the current CPU power *(read: anything [x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) produced since 2013)*, even on [BrowserStack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrowserStack), [Sauce Labs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sauce_Labs), and [AWS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) VMs, and the development of the browsers *(read: all the popular ones in the last five years)* that is hardly the case.

The browser's engines have developed, the support of XPath is uniform, and Internet Explorer is out of the picture *(hopefully for most of us)*. This comparison in the other answer is being cited all over the place, but it is very contextual – how many are running – or care about – automation against [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8)?

If there is a difference, it is in a *fraction of a millisecond*.

Yet, most higher-level frameworks add at least 1 ms of overhead over the raw selenium call anyway (wrappers, handlers, state storing, etc.); my personal weapon of choice – [Robot Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Framework) – adds at least 2 ms, which I am more than happy to sacrifice for what it provides. A network round trip from an AWS US-East-1 to BrowserStack's hub is usually **11 milliseconds**.

So with remote browsers, if there is a difference between XPath and CSS, it is overshadowed by everything else, in orders of magnitude.

---

### The measurements

There are not that many public comparisons *(I've really seen only the cited one)*, so – here's a rough single-case, dummy and simple one.

It will locate an element by the two strategies X times, and compare the average time for that.

The target – BrowserStack's landing page, and its "Sign Up" button; a screenshot of the HTML content as writing this post:

[image]

Here's the test code (Python):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import timeit


if __name__ == '__main__':

    xpath_locator = '//div[@class="button-section col-xs-12 row"]'
    css_locator = 'div.button-section.col-xs-12.row'

    repetitions = 1000

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.browserstack.com/')

    css_time = timeit.timeit("driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_locator)",
                             number=repetitions, globals=globals())
    xpath_time = timeit.timeit('driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath_locator)',
                               number=repetitions, globals=globals())

    driver.quit()

    print("CSS total time {} repeats: {:.2f} s, per find: {:.2f} ms".
          format(repetitions, css_time, (css_time/repetitions)*1000))
    print("XPATH total time for {} repeats: {:.2f} s, per find: {:.2f} ms".
          format(repetitions, xpath_time, (xpath_time/repetitions)*1000))
```

*For those not familiar with Python – it opens the page, and finds the element – first with the CSS locator, then with the XPath locator; the find operation is repeated 1,000 times. The output is the total time in seconds for the 1,000 repetitions, and average time for one find in milliseconds.*

The locators are:

- for XPath – "a *div* element having this exact class value, somewhere in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)";
- the CSS is similar – "a *div* element with this class, somewhere in the DOM".

It is deliberately chosen not to be over-tuned; also, the class selector is cited for the CSS as "the second fastest after an id".

The environment – Chrome v66.0.3359.139, [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started) v2.38, CPU: [ULV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-low-voltage_processor) Core M-5Y10 usually running at 1.5 GHz *(yes, a "word-processing" one, not even a regular [Core i7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_i7) beast)*.

Here's the output:

> ```
> CSS total time 1000 repeats: 8.84 s, per find: 8.84 ms
>
> XPath total time for 1000 repeats: 8.52 s, per find: 8.52 ms
> ```

Obviously, the per find timings are pretty close; the difference is **0.32** *milliseconds*. Don't jump "the XPath selector is faster" – sometimes it is, but sometimes it's CSS.

---

Let's try with another set of locators. It is a tiny-bit more complicated—an attribute having a substring *(common approach at least for me, going after an element's class when a part of it bears functional meaning)*:

```py
xpath_locator = '//div[contains(@class, "button-section")]'
css_locator = 'div[class~=button-section]'
```

The two locators are again semantically the same – "find a *div* element having in its class attribute this substring".

Here are the results:

> ```
> CSS total time 1000 repeats: 8.60 s, per find: 8.60 ms
>
> XPath total time for 1000 repeats: 8.75 s, per find: 8.75 ms
> ```

A difference of **0.15 ms**.

---

As an exercise—the same test as done in the [linked blog](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css) in the comments/other answer—the [test page](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables) is public, and so is the [testing code](https://gist.github.com/tourdedave/8309313).

They are doing a couple of things in the code - clicking on a column to sort by it, then getting the values, and checking the UI sort is correct.

I'll cut it - just get the locators, after all - this is the root test, right?

The same code as above, with these changes in:

- The URL is now `http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables`; there are two tests.
- The locators for the first one - "Finding Elements By ID and Class" - are:

```py
css_locator = '#table2 tbody .dues'
xpath_locator = "//table[@id='table2']//tr/td[contains(@class,'dues')]"
```

And here is the outcome:

> ```
> CSS total time 1000 repeats: 8.24 s, per find: 8.24 ms
>
> XPath total time for 1000 repeats: 8.45 s, per find: 8.45 ms
> ```

A difference of **0.2** milliseconds.

The "Finding Elements By Traversing":

```py
css_locator = '#table1 tbody tr td:nth-of-type(4)'
xpath_locator = "//table[@id='table1']//tr/td[4]"
```

The result:

> ```
> CSS total time 1000 repeats: 9.29 s, per find: 9.29 ms
>
> XPath total time for 1000 repeats: 8.79 s, per find: 8.79 ms
> ```

This time it is **0.5** ms (in reverse, XPath turned out "faster" here).

So five years later (better browsers engines) *and* focusing only on the locators performance (no actions like sorting in the UI, etc), the same testbed - there is practically no difference between CSS and XPath.

---

## The Best/Fastest/Hip Strategy?

So, out of XPath and CSS, which of the two to choose for performance? The answer is simple – choose **locating by id**.

Long story short, if the id of an element is unique (as it's supposed to be according to the specifications), its value plays an important role in the browser's internal representation of the DOM, and thus is usually the fastest.

Fun fact - [the webdriver protocol actually does not support locator strategy "by id"](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies). When one uses `By.ID` in selenium, what it actually does is to transform it to a css selector in the form "any element having an `id` attribute with the requested value".
Still, the browsers optimize the css engines heavily, and it ends up in the advantage section of the DOM representation.

Yet, unique and constant *(e.g. not auto-generated)* ids are not always available, which brings us to "why XPath if there's CSS?"

---

## The XPath advantage

With the performance out of the picture, why do I think XPath is better? Simple – versatility, and power.

XPath is a language developed for working with XML documents; as such, it allows for much more powerful constructs than CSS.

For example, navigation in every direction in the tree—find an element, then go to its grandparent and search for a child of it having certain properties.
It allows embedded boolean conditions—`cond1 and not(cond2 or not(cond3 and cond4))`; embedded selectors —"find a div having these children with these attributes, and then navigate according to it".

XPath allows searching based on a node's value (its text)—however frowned upon this practice is. It does come in handy especially in badly structured documents *(no definite attributes to step on, like dynamic ids and classes - locate the element by its text content)*.

The stepping in CSS is definitely easier—one can start writing selectors in a matter of minutes; but after a couple of days of usage, the power and possibilities XPath has quickly overcomes CSS.

And purely subjective – a complex CSS expression is much harder to read than a complex XPath expression.

### Outro ;)

Finally, again very subjective - which one should we chose?

IMO, there isn’t any right or wrong choice—they are different solutions to the same problem, and whatever is more suitable for the job should be picked.

Being "a fan" of XPath I'm not shy to use in my projects a mix of both - heck, sometimes it is much faster to just throw a CSS one, if I know it will do the work just fine.

Comment: How many nodes have the login page? Login pages are usually very simple so that's why you might have seen just little difference.

Comment: Other performance tests show much bigger difference across different browsers.

Comment: For your first question - a screenshot of the DOM is present in the answer, and the page is online and public. For your first and second, if you read the answer carefully I've repeated the same test as elementalselenium, one of the few available comparisons that is quite often cited, using the same target and locators as them, but just with 5 years newer browsers.

Comment: @TodorMinakov GREAT POST!!! I agree with you 100% I also think that XPath syntax is also more natural (at least to me) because it resembles something we all know very well. And that is file/folder paths. So I think a person with zero knowledge of CSS or XPath, will learn XPath much easier. Since performance difference is negligible, I think learning curve merits strong consideration.

Comment: Thank you @hfontanez; great analogy with the file system structure, I haven't thought of it. I have to disagree a tiny bit for the step-in easiness though - the XPath syntax can be a bit intimidating at first, plus it has some gotcha-s _(index `[]` after `//` for example)_. But after the initial day of learning and using it, pretty much everyone crosses the tipping point of the learning curve :) _(css step in is admitably easier, IMHO)_.

Comment: Has anything updated been done since what you've written above?  Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: No reason to; the computing power has only increased, even on mobiles, so the difference is as negligable as it was. xpath2 is still not supported in browsers (different topic)

Answer (score 19):

The debate between *cssSelector* vs *XPath* would remain as one of the most subjective debate in the *Selenium Community*. What we already know so far can be summarized as:

- People in favor of *cssSelector* say that it is more readable and faster (especially when running against Internet Explorer).
- While those in favor of *XPath* tout it's ability to transverse the page (while *cssSelector* cannot).
- Traversing the DOM in older browsers like IE8 does not work with *cssSelector* but is fine with *XPath*.
- *XPath* can walk up the DOM (e.g. from child to parent), whereas *cssSelector* can only traverse down the DOM (e.g. from parent to child)
- However not being able to traverse the DOM with *cssSelector* in older browsers isn't necessarily a bad thing as it is more of an indicator that your page has poor design and could benefit from some helpful markup.
- *Ben Burton* mentions you should use *cssSelector* because that's how applications are built. This makes the tests easier to write, talk about, and have others help maintain.
- *Adam Goucher* says to adopt a more hybrid approach -- focusing first on IDs, then *cssSelector*, and leveraging *XPath* only when you need it (e.g. walking up the DOM) and that *XPath* will always be more powerful for advanced locators.

*Dave Haeffner* carried out a [*test*](https://gist.github.com/tourdedave/8309313) on [*a page with two HTML data tables*](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/tables), one table is written without helpful attributes (*ID* and *Class*), and the other with them. I have analyzed the *test procedure* and the outcome of this experiment in details in the discussion [Why should I ever use *cssSelector* selectors as opposed to XPath for automated testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51936193/why-should-i-ever-use-css-selectors-as-opposed-to-xpath-for-automated-testing/51942615#51942615). While this experiment demonstrated that each [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) is reasonably equivalent across browsers, it didn't adequately paint the whole picture for us. *Dave Haeffner* in the other discussion [Css Vs. X Path, Under a Microscope](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/33-xpath-vs-css-revisited) mentioned, in an an end-to-end test there were a lot of other variables at play *Sauce startup*, *Browser start up*, and *latency* to and from the application under test. The unfortunate takeaway from that experiment could be that one driver may be faster than the other (e.g. *IE* vs *Firefox*), when in fact, that's wasn't the case at all. To get a real taste of what the performance difference is between *cssSelector* and *XPath*, we needed to dig deeper. We did that by running everything from a local machine while using a performance benchmarking utility. We also focused on a specific Selenium action rather than the entire test run, and run things numerous times. I have analyzed the specific *test procedure* and the outcome of this experiment in details in the discussion [cssSelector vs XPath for selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267591/cssselector-vs-xpath-for-selenium/54605738#54605738). But the tests were still missing one aspect i.e. *more browser coverage (e.g., Internet Explorer 9 and 10) and testing against a larger and deeper page.*

*Dave Haeffner* in another discussion [Css Vs. X Path, Under a Microscope (Part 2)](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2) mentions, in order to make sure the required benchmarks are covered in the best possible way we need to consider [an example that demonstrates a large and deep page](http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/large).

---

### Test SetUp

To demonstrate this detailed example, a Windows XP virtual machine was setup and [Ruby (1.9.3)](https://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) was installed. All the available browsers and their equivalent browser drivers for Selenium was also installed. For benchmarking, Ruby's standard lib [**`benchmark`**](http://rubylearning.com/blog/2013/06/19/how-do-i-benchmark-ruby-code/) was used.

---

### Test Code

```
require_relative 'base'
require 'benchmark'

class LargeDOM < Base

  LOCATORS = {
    nested_sibling_traversal: {
      css: "div#siblings > div:nth-of-type(1) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3) > div:nth-of-type(3)",
      xpath: "//div[@id='siblings']/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]"
    },
    nested_sibling_traversal_by_class: {
      css: "div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1 > div.item-1",
      xpath: "//div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]/div[contains(@class, 'item-1')]"
    },
    table_header_id_and_class: {
      css: "table#large-table thead .column-50",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']//thead//*[@class='column-50']"
    },
    table_header_id_class_and_direct_desc: {
      css: "table#large-table > thead .column-50",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']/thead//*[@class='column-50']"
    },
    table_header_traversing: {
      css: "table#large-table thead tr th:nth-of-type(50)",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']//thead//tr//th[50]"
    },
    table_header_traversing_and_direct_desc: {
      css: "table#large-table > thead > tr > th:nth-of-type(50)",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']/thead/tr/th[50]"
    },
    table_cell_id_and_class: {
      css: "table#large-table tbody .column-50",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']//tbody//*[@class='column-50']"
    },
    table_cell_id_class_and_direct_desc: {
      css: "table#large-table > tbody .column-50",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']/tbody//*[@class='column-50']"
    },
    table_cell_traversing: {
      css: "table#large-table tbody tr td:nth-of-type(50)",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']//tbody//tr//td[50]"
    },
    table_cell_traversing_and_direct_desc: {
      css: "table#large-table > tbody > tr > td:nth-of-type(50)",
      xpath: "//table[@id='large-table']/tbody/tr/td[50]"
    }
  }

  attr_reader :driver

  def initialize(driver)
    @driver = driver
    visit '/large'
    is_displayed?(id: 'siblings')
    super
  end

  # The benchmarking approach was borrowed from
  # http://rubylearning.com/blog/2013/06/19/how-do-i-benchmark-ruby-code/
  def benchmark
    Benchmark.bmbm(27) do |bm|
      LOCATORS.each do |example, data|
    data.each do |strategy, locator|
      bm.report(example.to_s + " using " + strategy.to_s) do
        begin
          ENV['iterations'].to_i.times do |count|
         find(strategy => locator)
          end
        rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError => error
          puts "( 0.0 )"
        end
      end
    end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

---

### Results

> **NOTE**: The output is in seconds, and the results are for the total run time of 100 executions.

In Table Form:

[image: css_xpath_under_microscopev2]

In Chart Form:

- **Chrome**:

[image: chart-chrome]

- **Firefox**:

[image: chart-firefox]

- **Internet Explorer 8**:

[image: chart-ie8]

- **Internet Explorer 9**:

[image: chart-ie9]

- **Internet Explorer 10**:

[image: chart-ie10]

- **Opera**:

[image: chart-opera]

---

### Analyzing the Results

- Chrome and Firefox are clearly tuned for faster *cssSelector* performance.
- Internet Explorer 8 is a grab bag of *cssSelector* that won't work, an out of control *XPath* traversal that takes ~65 seconds, and a 38 second table traversal with no *cssSelector* result to compare it against.
- In IE 9 and 10, *XPath* is faster overall. In Safari, it's a toss up, except for a couple of slower traversal runs with *XPath*. And across almost all browsers, [the nested sibling traversal](https://github.com/tourdedave/selenium-benchmark/blob/master/lib/page-objects/large_dom.rb#L13) and [table cell traversal](https://github.com/tourdedave/selenium-benchmark/blob/master/lib/page-objects/large_dom.rb#L41) done with *XPath* are an expensive operation.
- These shouldn't be that surprising since the locators are brittle and inefficient and we need to avoid them.

---

### Summary

- Overall there are two circumstances where *XPath* is markedly slower than *cssSelector*. But they are easily avoidable.
- The performance difference is slightly in favor of [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors) for non-IE browsers and slightly in favor of [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) for IE browsers.

---

### Trivia

You can perform the bench-marking on your own, using [this library](https://github.com/tourdedave/selenium-benchmark) where *Dave Haeffner* wrapped up all the code.