# Selenium Webdriver is very inconsistent during Execution of test scripts

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

We have a Keyword driven framework which was developed using Selenium Webdriver.
While running the scripts some test cases are getting timed out in the first run. When I do the second run the same test cases which failed last time pass but this time some other test cases fail.

Can someone please advise if anything needs to be done on the Framework/Configuration part.

I am using IE9, Java 6, Selenium 2.40 on Windows 7 and IE driver from the official Selenium website.

Comment: Can you provide an example of one of the tests?  This sounds like a timing issue on the execution something that is particularly in issue with IE.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Sainath,

The Secret to run TestCases efficiently lies in the Way You wrote the TestCases.. Use of **Fluent wait**, Wait before the Element is Visible and Enabled and use of html *ID's* in Testcases makes the TCs Efficient. IE and Selenium Does not get along almost all time.. i mean,, There are so many Issues with IE and Selenium.

The Only way to Achieve Efficiency is by Proper *Handling of Exceptions* and Use of *Wait* statements

Comment: horrible answer

Comment: This answer is very vague on what the OP was asking for.

Answer (score 4):

Your tests could be brittle because of various reasons.

**1. Synchronization**- DO NOT USE `Thread.sleep`. You should consider the waiting mechanism in your tests.
There are two types of waits in WebDriver. Implicit wait and Explicit
wait.

***a. Implicit wait-*** For example below `WebDriver` will internally poll *at max* for 30 seconds before throwing `NoSuchElementFoundException`

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

***b. Explicit wait***- Here you are telling WebDriver to wait for a certain condition to satisfy. For example, below I am waiting for the link `Account` to be available to click. Once its available WebDriver will return me the `WebElement` so that I can click on it. Take a look at some already implemented useful [ExpectedConditions](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html)

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30/*Timeout in seconds*/);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Account")));
element.click();
```

**2. Data Dependency**- Make sure your tests are independent of each other and they don't share data. Tests can collide if they are sharing data which makes them brittle

**3. Use CSS over Xpaths** - Find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t/16794683#16794683) as to why

**4. A layer of abstraction**- Make sure you have abstracted test logic from page logic. Use PageObjects and PageFactory technics for better maintenance of your suite

Finally read Simon Stewarts' blog on [Automated Web Testing: Traps for the Unwary](https://conference.eurostarsoftwaretesting.com/liveblogged-automated-web-testing-traps-unwary-simon-stewart/) for details.

Comment: The link  'Automated Web Testing: Traps for the Unwary' is dead.

Comment: fixed the link now

Comment: The link 'Automated Web Testing for the Unwary' is dead again, but here is a link to a YouTube video of it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96jHVyJyrZ8

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest making sure that the keywords you are using are not dynamically generated.

I worked on a site once where all of the ID's looked like this: 'ext-gen123', then the next run through, the very same element would have the ID: 'ext-gen124', but the run through after that would have the ID back to 'ext-gen123'...

In this case, you'd have to use some other identifier to locate the element--maybe a CssClass or an XPath.

Comment: Thanks @autoKarma for Replying... i have looked into the DOM elements and the id's are all not dynamic... just wondering is this anything to do with webdriver.

Comment: If dynamic id's are not a problem, the like @nislesh and METIsatish said--constructing proper waits will probably help you out. Try it, and if you're still having trouble, come back and let us know. (But if waits were the answer, try to make sure you mark nilesh or NETIsatish's answer as accepted) :)

Comment: Thanks @autoKarma i will let you all know the results