# How do I find this button with Selenium? I tried partiallinktext and multiple attempts at cssSelector

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to find the button inside of this table.  The ideal would be to find it by the 'Course Home' text because that's how users find it, but at this point, since that's not what I'm testing, I'm willing use any method as long as it can find and click on the button.

I have tried:

- By.cssSelector("div.buttons:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)") //least favorite method
- By.partialLinkText("Course Home");//the ideal
- By.cssSelector("div.two>div.buttons>button")// and other such attempts, just grasping at straws

but none of these work.  My test just hangs, looking for the button until it hits the timeout.  What am I doing wrong?
PS I'm using Java.

```
    <td valign="middle">
        <div class="two">
            <div class="buttons">
                <button onclick="document.location.href='file/path/redacted/'">
                    <img src="/images/button_icons/house.png">
                    Course Home
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using xpath as:

```
By.xpath("//button/img[.='Course Home']");
```

or

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Course Home')]");
```

Comment: Does using xpath mean I won't be able to test in IE?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can go on using it in IE.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of text based search of `xpath`

```
//*[.='Course Home']
```

Just need to make sure the text includes all the leading or tailing spaces and that's pretty much it. With `.` it gives us the ability to directly point to the parent node of the element wheres `*` search any tag on the page

Comment: Does using xpath mean I won't be able to run tests on IE?

Comment: No I use IE for my testing as well. It's little slow sometimes but works

Comment: @user3352335 IE doesn't have native xpath engine, therefore using xpath on IE has performance implications and inconsistencies with how other browsers behave for certain xpaths

Answer (score 0):

I prefer CSS over xpath and my answer on that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t)

As for your solution xpath options provided by Vivek and Saifur should work too. I will provide some css options

```
 div.buttons>button
```

or

```
 div.two>div.buttons>button
```

or

```
 div.two button
```