# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException when element is actually visible

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

[image: screenshot of the IFrame]

Scenarion: After clicking New button it will be disable and then need to input the data in field Name text field. It works in Mozilla but not in IE.

IE version -8
IEDriver -IEDriverServer_x64_2.44.0

Comment: What code you have tried? Try to imply some explicit wait like `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)`...thanks...

Comment: I tried that too.. Waiting for 30 seconds.
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(object))));

Comment: can u provide html in IE please...

Comment: shall I contact you in person? Need mail ID

Answer (score 0):

try to use alternative [CSS selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) approach because:

- CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath and it is well documented
  in Selenium community
- Xpath engines are different in each browser, hence make them
  inconsistent
- IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium injects
  its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the
  advantage of using native browser features that WebDriver inherently
  promotes.
- Xpath tend to become complex and hence make hard to read in my
  opinion However there are some situations where, you need to use
  xpath, for example, searching for a parent element or searching
  element by its text (I wouldn't recommend the later).

More details on performance comparison you can get [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t)

After you start make any actions on the webElements also it better to wait until the whole page renders. Here are some tricks that would help you:
1) `waitForPageLoad()` method:

```
public void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver_) {

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver_, 30);
        wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {

                return String
                        .valueOf(((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState"))
                        .equals("complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

2) [fluentWait](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) method -An implementation of the Wait interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly.

```
 public WebElement fluentWait(WebDriver driver, final By locator) {
        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        // .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        // .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
                .ignoring(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException.class);

        WebElement foo = wait.until(
                new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        return driver.findElement(locator);
                    }
                }
        );
        return foo;
    }
```

once you add these methods you can use following calls:

```
// css selector of the input field:
String cssSelectorInput="blablabla" 
waitForPageLoad(driver);
WebElement input= fluentWait(driver, By.cssSelector(cssSelectorInput));
input.sendKeys("test name");

..... etc
```

Hope this helps you.