# html table row count using Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to count the total number of rows (excluding header) in my HTML table using Selenium Webdriver-Java.

Can someone please guide me in correct direction regarding the steps for the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can this be achieved using 'xpath' ??

Answer (score 6):

If you could provide HTML around your table, we could provide more accurate selector in your case. Something like this should work. Hope you get the idea!

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table#dummyTable>tbody>tr"));
System.out.println("Total number of rows :"+ rows.size());
```

or using xpath

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//table[@id='dummyTable']/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Total number of rows :"+ rows.size());
```

Comment: findElements, with an s on the end, will be needed

Comment: Can you please share the alternative solution using 'xpath'

Comment: Updated answer with xpath. However curious to know why do you need to use xpath? I recommend css over xpath. Check my answer here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t

Comment: I tried the above mentioned options but its giving me count as zero. Any other way I can try this?

Comment: List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/form[1]/section/table/tbody/tr"));
System.out.println("Total number of rows :"+ rows.size());

Comment: Like I said, provide brief HTML around the table. that will help get you a better selector. Xpath you mention in the comment is brittle and hard to read/maintain. You need a better selector

Comment: <form id=[abcd] name="Form1">

    <input id=[1234] type="hidden" name=[1234]></input>
    <header id=[34567]></header>
    <div class=[name]></div>
    <section id=[name]>
        <b></b>
        <em></em>
        <table id="dummyTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" name="dummyTable">
            <tbody>
                <tr class=[def]></tr>.......so on further <tr> tags.

Comment: I hope above HTML around the table will help.

Comment: I updated selector in the answer. Try it now

Comment: Its still showing count as zero.

Comment: what did you try? Is your real table id `dummyTable`? If not you would need to update it with real value in the original answer

Comment: Yes, I updated the table id with actual table name but its still giving count as zero.

Comment: Did you try xpath or CSS or both? Make sure you haven't misspelled anything

Comment: I tried xpath and cssSelector both but its not working.

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: No. I am not getting any errors. It directly displays the output as:

Total number of rows :0

Comment: @KetanDeopujari Update your question with the HTML. Nilesh's answer should work. Post errors if you see any. If you still see zero, then it means we are running the code even before the table is loaded. Hence, we may need to wait for the table to be loaded and then count the columns.

Comment: @KetanDeopujari `findElements` will not throw any error, if the css selector does not match it will give an empty array of elements and hence the size is zero. I still think the css selector is incorrect.

Comment: One way to verify selector I guess to use findElement and check if it throws exception. Oh hey hi LINGS :)