# Locating an element by id

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, protractor

What is the difference between the following location techniques?

1. `element(by.id("id"));`
2. `element(by.css("#id"));`
3. `element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"));`
4. `browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#id');");`
5. `browser.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id');");`

And, from the *performance perspective*, which would be the fastest way to locate an element by id?

Comment: I'm going to guess that #1 is fastest.  In fact, you may well already have them ranked in order (but with #4 and #5 reversed).  Looking forward to some strong analytical or empirical answers.

Comment: These are strategy to identify page element locator, By.id is best it is fast, not dependent on other html tag. You can create locator using css or xpath when you have any unique attribute for particular element. css is fast compare to xpath

Comment: @SadikAli Thank you for the input. "css is fast compare to xpath" - should not it depend on a particular browser? Do you have any reference or a benchmark to provide?..

Comment: It would probably need an another bounty or two to reward the detailed answers here. Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is very difficult to answer, certainly to give a single conclusive answer. In fact, I am tempted to flag this question as "too broad", which is supported by the other answers and comments.

Take, for example, just your `element(by.id("id"));`. Looking through the Selenium source, *most* drivers just take whatever id you give, and pass it off to the wire protocol:

```
public WebElement findElementById(String using) {
  if (getW3CStandardComplianceLevel() == 0) {
    return findElement("id", using);
  } else {
    return findElementByCssSelector("#" + cssEscape(using));
  }
}
```

As you know, each browser vendor implements their own wire protocol in a separate binary. Feel free to go further into the code, to dig a deeper hole for your self.

For other browsers that do not support the wire protocol, for example HtmlUnit, you just have something like:

```
public List<WebElement> findElementsById(String id) {
  return findElementsByXPath("//*[@id='" + id + "']");
}
```

and then they parse the available DOM.

As for your performance question, anything that anyone gives you will be 1) just a *feeling*, or 2) pure BS! Which you can already see from the other answers and comments you are getting.

To get a *real* answer (supported by actual data), there are just too many variables to consider:

- Wire protocol as implemented by different browser vendors, plus various optimizations in different versions.
- DOM engines as implemented by different browser vendors, plus various optimizations in different versions.
- JavaScript engines as implemented by different browser vendors, plus various optimizations in different versions.

Also, whatever results you get for your web app / web page will most like not apply to a different web app / web page, due to differences in the framework used to build that site.

Bottom line is: If you are concerned about performance testing, then Selenium is the wrong answer. Selenium is a functional test library, optimized to give you the best end-user representation. Performance is a distant afterthought.

If your goal is to get your tests to run faster, your time will be better spent looking at your test structure:

- How frequently do you open/close the browser. This is often the most time consuming activity in a test.
- How often do you refresh your element cache, how often do you *need* to? Consider moving your elements to Page **Factory** model, which lazy-loads all elements for you.
- And of course the biggest speedup factor: running your tests in parallel on multiple machines.

But I think this is getting off topic (some might suggest "ranty") from your initial question.

Comment: Yes, this question is "very difficult to answer," but no, the differences between those forms are not "primarily opinion-based", and, no, performance is neither "just a feeling" nor "pure BS".  Performance may be complex to measure or context sensitive, but it is still very objective.  You have a kernel of a decent answer started here with your source investigation foray; it's a shame you surrounded that fine start by such unproductive ranting.  Why don't you edit it, remove the ranting, and build out the productive parts further?

Comment: @kjhughes I did say "... anything that anyone gives you ..." I do understand that getting **real** performance metrics is an art form. Look at the answers: "...I vote...", "...according to me...". Even your own comment is pre-pended with "I'm going to guess..." I fixed my answer slightly, feel free to downvote me if you still feel strongly about you position.

Comment: No downvote needed.  Thank you for the improvements you did make.

Answer (score 8):

I just think about performance perspective and write the following script to check google logo. Although the result is confusing, we can make an estimation the result statistically.

**querySelector** and **getElementById** have always better result, unless number of trials is more than 10K. If we compare these two method: **getElementById** is better (29 over 21).

If we compare these there, **ID**, **CSS** and **XPATH**, CSS is better (29 over 18 and 4), second is ID and last one XPATH.

The result from my test: **getElementById, querySelector, CSS, ID, XPATH**

See the table, result and script:

Table show the result in summary for 50 tries:

```
                1   2   3   4   5
ID              0   0   18  24  8
CSS             0   0   29  18  3
XPATH           0   0   4   12  34
querySelector   21  29  0   0   0
getElementById  29  21  0   0   0
```

Result with time diff:

```sh
>>> for i in range(50):
...  test_time(1)
...
[('getElementById', 0.004777193069458008), ('querySelector', 0.006440162658691406), ('id', 0.015267133712768555), ('css', 0.015399932861328125), ('xpath', 0.015429019927978516)]
[('querySelector', 0.006442070007324219), ('getElementById', 0.00728607177734375), ('id', 0.013181924819946289), ('css', 0.014509916305541992), ('xpath', 0.015583992004394531)]
[('getElementById', 0.0063440799713134766), ('querySelector', 0.006493091583251953), ('css', 0.014523029327392578), ('id', 0.014902830123901367), ('xpath', 0.015790224075317383)]
[('getElementById', 0.007112026214599609), ('querySelector', 0.007357120513916016), ('id', 0.014781951904296875), ('css', 0.015780925750732422), ('xpath', 0.016005992889404297)]
[('getElementById', 0.006434917449951172), ('querySelector', 0.007117033004760742), ('id', 0.01497507095336914), ('css', 0.015005111694335938), ('xpath', 0.015393972396850586)]
[('querySelector', 0.00563812255859375), ('getElementById', 0.006503105163574219), ('css', 0.014302968978881836), ('id', 0.014812946319580078), ('xpath', 0.017061948776245117)]
[('querySelector', 0.0048770904541015625), ('getElementById', 0.006540060043334961), ('css', 0.014795064926147461), ('id', 0.015192985534667969), ('xpath', 0.016000986099243164)]
[('getElementById', 0.006265878677368164), ('querySelector', 0.006501913070678711), ('id', 0.014132022857666016), ('css', 0.01437997817993164), ('xpath', 0.014840841293334961)]
[('getElementById', 0.006368160247802734), ('querySelector', 0.006601095199584961), ('css', 0.01462101936340332), ('id', 0.014872074127197266), ('xpath', 0.016145944595336914)]
[('querySelector', 0.00642704963684082), ('getElementById', 0.006908893585205078), ('css', 0.014439105987548828), ('id', 0.014970064163208008), ('xpath', 0.015510082244873047)]
[('getElementById', 0.006404876708984375), ('querySelector', 0.006679058074951172), ('css', 0.014878988265991211), ('id', 0.01546788215637207), ('xpath', 0.015535116195678711)]
[('querySelector', 0.005848884582519531), ('getElementById', 0.008013010025024414), ('css', 0.014436006546020508), ('xpath', 0.01566910743713379), ('id', 0.015830039978027344)]
[('querySelector', 0.006299018859863281), ('getElementById', 0.006538867950439453), ('css', 0.014534950256347656), ('id', 0.014979124069213867), ('xpath', 0.01618194580078125)]
[('getElementById', 0.006415128707885742), ('querySelector', 0.006479978561401367), ('id', 0.014901876449584961), ('css', 0.014998912811279297), ('xpath', 0.01544499397277832)]
[('getElementById', 0.006515979766845703), ('querySelector', 0.006515979766845703), ('xpath', 0.014292001724243164), ('css', 0.014482975006103516), ('id', 0.015102863311767578)]
[('getElementById', 0.00574803352355957), ('querySelector', 0.006389141082763672), ('css', 0.014650821685791016), ('id', 0.014751911163330078), ('xpath', 0.01532888412475586)]
[('getElementById', 0.0063037872314453125), ('querySelector', 0.006974935531616211), ('id', 0.014775991439819336), ('css', 0.014935970306396484), ('xpath', 0.015460968017578125)]
[('getElementById', 0.0064661502838134766), ('querySelector', 0.0065021514892578125), ('id', 0.014723062515258789), ('css', 0.014946937561035156), ('xpath', 0.015508890151977539)]
[('getElementById', 0.006738901138305664), ('querySelector', 0.008143901824951172), ('css', 0.014575004577636719), ('xpath', 0.015228986740112305), ('id', 0.015702009201049805)]
[('getElementById', 0.006436824798583984), ('querySelector', 0.0064470767974853516), ('css', 0.014545917510986328), ('id', 0.014694929122924805), ('xpath', 0.015357017517089844)]
[('querySelector', 0.006292104721069336), ('getElementById', 0.006451845169067383), ('css', 0.014657020568847656), ('xpath', 0.01574397087097168), ('id', 0.016795873641967773)]
[('getElementById', 0.006443977355957031), ('querySelector', 0.006485939025878906), ('css', 0.013139009475708008), ('id', 0.014308929443359375), ('xpath', 0.015516042709350586)]
[('querySelector', 0.006464958190917969), ('getElementById', 0.006821870803833008), ('id', 0.016110897064208984), ('css', 0.01633286476135254), ('xpath', 0.017225980758666992)]
[('getElementById', 0.005715131759643555), ('querySelector', 0.008069992065429688), ('css', 0.014779090881347656), ('id', 0.01491093635559082), ('xpath', 0.015527963638305664)]
[('getElementById', 0.006309986114501953), ('querySelector', 0.006836891174316406), ('css', 0.01497507095336914), ('id', 0.015040159225463867), ('xpath', 0.02096104621887207)]
[('querySelector', 0.00616908073425293), ('getElementById', 0.007357120513916016), ('css', 0.014974832534790039), ('id', 0.015640974044799805), ('xpath', 0.016278982162475586)]
[('querySelector', 0.005301952362060547), ('getElementById', 0.0063440799713134766), ('id', 0.014526844024658203), ('css', 0.014657974243164062), ('xpath', 0.0162200927734375)]
[('querySelector', 0.005811929702758789), ('getElementById', 0.007221221923828125), ('css', 0.01259613037109375), ('xpath', 0.014851093292236328), ('id', 0.015043020248413086)]
[('getElementById', 0.006195068359375), ('querySelector', 0.007548093795776367), ('css', 0.01441502571105957), ('id', 0.01441812515258789), ('xpath', 0.016713857650756836)]
[('querySelector', 0.0050449371337890625), ('getElementById', 0.006323099136352539), ('id', 0.01497793197631836), ('css', 0.014984130859375), ('xpath', 0.015444040298461914)]
[('getElementById', 0.007039070129394531), ('querySelector', 0.008107900619506836), ('xpath', 0.015566825866699219), ('id', 0.015954017639160156), ('css', 0.01815509796142578)]
[('getElementById', 0.005831003189086914), ('querySelector', 0.007988214492797852), ('id', 0.014652013778686523), ('css', 0.014683008193969727), ('xpath', 0.01581597328186035)]
[('querySelector', 0.006363868713378906), ('getElementById', 0.006494998931884766), ('xpath', 0.01517796516418457), ('id', 0.016071796417236328), ('css', 0.017260074615478516)]
[('getElementById', 0.00633692741394043), ('querySelector', 0.007826089859008789), ('css', 0.014354944229125977), ('id', 0.015484809875488281), ('xpath', 0.017076969146728516)]
[('querySelector', 0.006349802017211914), ('getElementById', 0.006428956985473633), ('css', 0.01385188102722168), ('id', 0.014858007431030273), ('xpath', 0.016836166381835938)]
[('querySelector', 0.006417989730834961), ('getElementById', 0.007012844085693359), ('css', 0.01460719108581543), ('id', 0.014763832092285156), ('xpath', 0.015476226806640625)]
[('getElementById', 0.006266117095947266), ('querySelector', 0.0074520111083984375), ('id', 0.014987945556640625), ('css', 0.01515817642211914), ('xpath', 0.015646934509277344)]
[('getElementById', 0.006376981735229492), ('querySelector', 0.0064089298248291016), ('id', 0.01494598388671875), ('css', 0.015275001525878906), ('xpath', 0.01553201675415039)]
[('getElementById', 0.006357908248901367), ('querySelector', 0.006699085235595703), ('css', 0.014505147933959961), ('xpath', 0.015446186065673828), ('id', 0.019747018814086914)]
[('getElementById', 0.0063610076904296875), ('querySelector', 0.0064640045166015625), ('css', 0.014472007751464844), ('id', 0.014828205108642578), ('xpath', 0.01532888412475586)]
[('getElementById', 0.0063610076904296875), ('querySelector', 0.006580829620361328), ('css', 0.012439966201782227), ('id', 0.014935016632080078), ('xpath', 0.015373945236206055)]
[('querySelector', 0.006309032440185547), ('getElementById', 0.006561994552612305), ('id', 0.014923095703125), ('css', 0.015380859375), ('xpath', 0.01574110984802246)]
[('querySelector', 0.006357908248901367), ('getElementById', 0.006387948989868164), ('css', 0.01481485366821289), ('id', 0.015089988708496094), ('xpath', 0.015390872955322266)]
[('querySelector', 0.004536867141723633), ('getElementById', 0.00640416145324707), ('css', 0.014551877975463867), ('xpath', 0.014974117279052734), ('id', 0.014991998672485352)]
[('getElementById', 0.006387233734130859), ('querySelector', 0.00643610954284668), ('css', 0.014494895935058594), ('id', 0.014873981475830078), ('xpath', 0.015212059020996094)]
[('getElementById', 0.0063588619232177734), ('querySelector', 0.006443977355957031), ('css', 0.013200998306274414), ('id', 0.014631986618041992), ('xpath', 0.015624046325683594)]
[('getElementById', 0.0048558712005615234), ('querySelector', 0.005300045013427734), ('id', 0.014750003814697266), ('css', 0.014846086502075195), ('xpath', 0.015408992767333984)]
[('querySelector', 0.008347034454345703), ('getElementById', 0.008370161056518555), ('id', 0.014650106430053711), ('css', 0.014775991439819336), ('xpath', 0.015323877334594727)]
[('querySelector', 0.006309032440185547), ('getElementById', 0.007323026657104492), ('css', 0.014546871185302734), ('xpath', 0.015864133834838867), ('id', 0.02078390121459961)]
[('querySelector', 0.007790088653564453), ('getElementById', 0.010209083557128906), ('id', 0.015320062637329102), ('xpath', 0.01600193977355957), ('css', 0.01807403564453125)]
```

Code:

```py
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import time, operator
from selenium import webdriver

def open_browser():
    dr = webdriver.Chrome()
    dr.get('http://www.google.com')
    time.sleep(5)
    return dr,timer()

def quit_browser(el, start, dr, result):
    diff = timer() - float(start)
    result[el] = diff
    dr.quit()

def test_time(tm):
    result = {}
    
    dr, start = open_browser()
    for i in range(tm):
        dr.find_element_by_id('hplogo')
    quit_browser("id", start, dr, result)
    
    dr, start = open_browser()
    for i in range(tm):
        dr.find_element_by_css_selector('#hplogo')
    quit_browser("css", start, dr, result)
    
    dr, start = open_browser()
    for i in range(tm):
        dr.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='hplogo']")
    quit_browser("xpath", start, dr, result)
    
    dr, start = open_browser()
    for i in range(tm):
        dr.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#hplogo');")
    quit_browser("querySelector", start, dr, result)
    
    dr, start = open_browser()
    for i in range(tm):
        dr.execute_script("return document.getElementById('hplogo');")
    quit_browser("getElementById", start, dr, result)
    
    print sorted(result.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Answer (score 4):

Identifying differences would be pretty tough. Here are few things that i found -

[`executeScript()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l526) schedules a command to execute JavaScript as a string in the context of the currently selected frame or window. Though this is fast, readability of code is low.

`element()` function in turn resolves to [`findElement()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/source/lib/webdriver/webdriver.js.src.html#l1857) function which schedules a command to find the element on the DOM. Improved readability.

From performance perspective according to me, here are the rankings in ascending order starting with the fastest and all of them were close to each other with differences in few milliseconds -

```
1 - browser.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id');");
2 - browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#id');");
3 - element(by.id("id"));
4 - element(by.css("#id"));
5 - element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"));
```

The reason for the javascript `executeScript()` being so fast is because the command its executed on DOM directly with no conversions. [This link justifies their rankings between each other](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector).

The remaining protractor specific `element()` locators are slow as protractor needs to convert the commands to get the web-elements using `findElement()` function. Getting element by `id` is faster than using `css` and `xpath` (This is also dependent on how the locators are being used and often can change based on usage).

**NOTE:** The above performance analysis was the average of many tests that i ran locally on my machine, but it can differ based on system tasks that internally affect running the test scripts.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

---

## TL;DR; performance in order from fast to slow.

- `element(by.id("id"));`
- `element(by.css("#id"));`
- `element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"));`
- `browser.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id');");`
- `browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#id');");`

---

I will give this a try. I will try to explain it until the point of `Protractor` and `WebdriverJS`. As I am not writing `Selenium` or browser's drivers (E.g. `Chromedriver`, `Firefoxdriver`... etc...) which is the communication between browsers and `Selenium`. For this I will use standard knowledge of browser's engine for this point. Therefore the answer, it will not 100% accurate but mostly.

## I will separate 5 methods in 2 groups:

### 1. Common communications

For the first 3 methods:

> element(by.id("id"));
>
> element(by.css("#id"));
>
> element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"));

These are all result with a single HTTP request to Selenium server. Which is:
    `'/session/:sessionId/element/:id/element'`

With 2 parameters:

- `using` : type of `:id` . Example: `'css select'`, `'id'`, '`xpath'`, `'link text'`... etc..
- `value` : value of `:id`. Example `'element-id'`, `'.element-css > .child'`, `//*[@id='id']`

At this point `Selenium` will answer the request accordingly to what is being requested through either of `Chromedriver`, `Firefoxdriver`... etc...

Under Webdriver [find-element-strategy.js](https://github.com/webdriverio/webdriverio/blob/master/lib/helpers/find-element-strategy.js) . As it is seem like methods are mapped with what browser providing by javascript `document` properties. We got `tag`, `id`, `css selector`, `xpath`... etc.. which are matched with `document.elementByTagName`, `document.elementByID`, `document.querySelecotr`, `document.evaluate`...

Logically in the point of view of a coder I will say the resource should be reuse regardless how these drivers got written. For example quest request for `id` it will most likely something like `getElementById` got to be trigger at browser side through the communication driver.

=> **SUMMARY** So in the end we have:

- `css selector` equivalent of `querySelector`
- `id` equivalent of `getElementById`
- `xpath` equivalent of `evaluate`

### 2. Injecting communications

For 2 last methods:

> browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#id');");
>
> browser.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id');");

These are all result with a single HTTP request to Selenium server. Which is:
    `'/session/:sessionId/execute'`

With 2 parameters:

- `script` : javascript text (`'string'`) or a `function`
- `args` : arguments is an `array`

Until this point it with be about how JS got injected into browser, as none of us can be sure the behavior (either using `devtools` or inject `<script>` into HTML). Let's just assume that it will be the same for all browser.

=> **SUMMARY** So in the end we will analyze :

- `querySelector`
- `getElementById`

---

## Main comparison

### **1.** **`element()`** vs **`browser.executeScript()`**:

- **element()** Original made to locate elements. It's using all the method profile by browser and it communication driver. This will result as faster performance
- **browser.executeScript()** was original **not** made to use to locating an element. But to execute a script, by using it we are of course getting same result but going through more complicating way to achieve the same goal. Therefore this will result in a more complicated calculation than using element finder. And ended up result a slower performance.

**=> SUMMARY** fast to slow

- `element()`
- `browser.executeScript()`

### **2.** **`document.querySelector()`** vs **`document.getElementById()`** vs **`document.querySelector()`**:

Again each browser will result a slightly difference. But there are already some research about this. I will just use what community has been found.

`CSS selector` being know that faster than `xpath` ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16794683/1729688))

`document.querySelector()` > FASTER > `document.evaluate()`

(NOTE: xpath is not supported by IE, so selenium using its own xpath engine whenever you are using xpath on IE with protractor)

On [`jsperf.com`](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/25) we got [**this**](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector/25) test that saying

`document.getElementById()` > FASTER > `document.querySelector()`

**=> SUMARY** fast to slow

- `document.getElementById()`
- `document.querySelector()`
- `document.evaluate()`

### **3. Sum up performance of method from fast to slow**

- `element(by.id("id"));`
- `element(by.css("#id"));`
- `element(by.xpath("//*[@id='id']"));`
- `browser.executeScript("return document.getElementById('id');");`
- `browser.executeScript("return document.querySelector('#id');");`

Answer (score 0):

It would be a broad answer if someone tries to answer it so I will try to make it as simple as I can.

These are just different ways of finding elements using selenium. The reason why we have so many alternatives to select elements is, not always we will have id or class tagged to an element. For elements which do not have id or class or name the only option left with us is XPATH.

XPATH can be used to uniquely identify any element in an XML and since HTML (HTML 5 to be precise, if written according to standards) is an instance of XML we can use XPATH to uniquely identify every element in the file.

OK so why not use XPATH all the time? Why so many alternatives? 
Simple, XPATH is difficult to write. For example if we need to get the XPATH of a **'td'** which belongs to a table nested inside 2 other tables. XPATH will be pretty long and most of the time we tend to make a mistake.

Finding XPATH in firefox is pretty straight forward, simply install firepath or firebug and right click on the element and select COPY XPATH.

Detailed instructions on indicators in selenium: [here](http://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html) (presented in java but will help in general)

Comment: It is not always true that "HTML is an instance of XML".  HTML can be written to be compliant with the XML specification, but most versions of HTML (including HTML5) allow things that would be invalid XML.  For instance `<br>` is valid in HTML, but must be written `<br/>` in XML and `<input type="checkbox" checked>` is valid in HTML, but not in XML.

Comment: Yeah @Matthew you are right. Not always HTML is an instance of XML but HTML 5 standard requires HTML to be compliant with XML. Thanks for the comment. I will edit the response.

Comment: Actually not even true for HTML5.  The specification allows one to write it in either an XML compliant form or not.  Notice for instance in the definition of the `<br>` [tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element), that the specification does not require the tag to be closed, and for the `<p>` [tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element), the specification tells when the end tag can be omitted (which is never allowed in XML).

Comment: Yes the specification allows people to write in XML compliant format or a bit sloppy format too but the most important introduction of HTML 5 is to be more like XHTML and not like HTML 4. XHTML is more strict and if written according to XHTML we are actually writing XML compliant code. But i do accept your comment, most developers let the sloppy methods of writing HTML creep in most of the time.