# When should I use XPath?

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Consider the following example, where a `ul` element's id is known, and we want to `Click()` its containing `li` element if the `li.Text` equals a certain text.

Here are two working solutions to this problem:

---

**Method 1:** Using XPath

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lis = FindElements(By.XPath("//ul[@id='id goes here']/li"));
foreach (IWebElement li in lis) {
    if (li.Text == text) {
        li.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

**Method 2:** Using ID and TagName

```
IWebElement ul = FindElement(By.Id("id goes here"));
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> lis = ul.FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
foreach (IWebElement li in lis) {
    if (li.Text == text) {
        li.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

---

**My question is: When should we use XPath and when shouldn't we?**

I prefer to use XPath only when necessary. For this specific example, I think that XPath is completely unnecessary, but when I looked up this specific problem on StackOverflow, it seems that a majority of users default to using XPath.

Comment: Use whatever you are more comfortable with! Have a read through a recent discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34521441/3124333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, XPath can even simplify the problem to a single line:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//ul[@id='id goes here']/li[. = '{0}']", text))).click();
```

In general though, if you can uniquely identify an element using simple `By.Id` or `By.TagName` or other similar "simple" locators, do it. XPath expression and CSS selector based locators usually either provide advanced ways to locate elements (we can go up/down/sideways in the tree, use partial attribute matches, count elements, determine their position etc) or make the element's location concise, as in this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. When you need to track more similar web elements use XPATH.
2. When you need particular single element use id

Xpath having more advantage, because sometimes id get duplicate
This is my experience!

Comment: But if id get duplicate, it is a bug to fix. Id needs to be unique in a html page.

Comment: id is unique OK. Just imagine, You working on thirdparty sites, here how you solve your duplicate id problem without xpath.

Comment: Even in Jquery you cannot select an duplicated ID using #. So, if you are working as tester to a thirdparty sites is your duty flag it as an error: code error and navigation error. But if you really want to ignore the duplicated id, you can use the xpath. The same as you can program using quick fix, but nobody will like to support your code, and do it will be hard some months later.

Comment: I know and Accept. Internal projects means yours best, when you test again thirdparty means xpath best.(we choose selector as per the situation)