# Selenium DOM Search Order

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testcomplete

I know this question can be tricky, would take help/suggestions. if duplicate/bad , pls lemme know via comments I will delete.

I would like to understand how Selenium searches within the tree structure of a DOM.

(*The reason why i asked is i switched from Testcomplete just now. Testcomplete searches from the bottom up. The bottom most elements gets searched faster. Also if there are 10 elements with same id, and we try findelement and not findallelements, it will give the bottom most element*)

So Selenium - does it start from top or bottom of a tree branch?. Let's see the tree is as below

```
<div>  
    <section1>
        <h1>
        </h1>
        <h2>
        </h2>
   </section1>
    <section2>
        <i1>
        </i1>
   </section2>
   <section3>
        <j1>
            <k1 id='something'>
            </k1>
        </j1>
        <j2>
        </j2>
   </section3>
</div>
```

I am searching for Element id = something.

1. Does it first look out for `Section 1, h1` tag and then traverses down ? or it starts from `Section 3 j2` tag and starts upwards?. The reason is, in a very lengthy AngularJs page, searching for a table at the top gives faster results and a table in the bottom takes around 15 seconds almost.
2. Second - does it search like serially ? or Vertically?.

   Serially - Search `Section1, h1, h2, section2, i1` etc.

   Vertically -  Search `Section1, section2, section3` and then `h1,h2,i1` etc.

Understanding this would go a long way in establishing a good element locator strategy.

Comment: The answer to this is going to be very *similar* to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34645549/3124333

Comment: Hmm yes a good one. I will collect these. will try to test across various pages.

Comment: can you please look at one of my q regarding jenkins set up???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you do a findElement in Selenium it will give you the element that first appears on the page in the same logical order that a findElement would return if you did this in JavaScript.

Obviously, there are multiple ways to do a lookup and the exact implementation is going to be dependant on the driver implementation (FireFox, Google, IE, etc)  But I have always gotten what I would expect and not anything like the wacky TC.

My answer is based on my own experience with the product.  I can't find any exact authoritative source that would document this for you.

Comment: I would'nt say the TC is wacky. It's just that Javascript implementation and TC would list out in a certain order. And by the way they are using JScript - microsoft javascript implementation. Secondly I am not able to understand if you answered for traversing order of tags. its very important I find it because if there is some vertical search, we can narrow it down faster using xpath. I am trying that though

Comment: My experience is that it is in the order the HTML list out.  Depth first search.  XPath, if you can do it, may be faster by milliseconds.  Not something I would worry about other than specifying exactly which element you are looking for.

Comment: Lemme try to verify that. I need to probably create a custom Html for that

Comment: Any hints suggestion - what exact javascript command Selenium uses for searching ?

Comment: Like I said, that is going to depend on the driver implementation.