# Send_keys() doesn´t send the full string

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

I´m trying to login to a website with selenium and Chrome in Python. I´m able to locate the user and password field, and the button. The only thing I´m not capable of is filling the password field with all the string. It writes a substring, with varying lengths.

**My code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Visente\Desktop\Pablito Python\chromedriver.exe")

urlbet='https://www.bet365.es/?&cb=103265469#/HO/'

browser.get(urlbet)

sport=WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="dv1"]/a')))

sport.click()

user=WebDriverWait(browser,
10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/input')))      

passw=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/input[1]')     


user.send_keys('my_user')
passw.send_keys('password')  

submit=browser.find_element_by_xpath(
'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button')`  

submit.click()
```

So, in short, the line where y use send_keys() on variable `passw` is not writing the full length of the password and I don´t know why.
By the way, how do I get back the text I just sent with sed_keys() in order to know what is being passed and what is missing from the string?

Comment: How you propose to do it? Bear in mind that after sending the first character, the x_path changues so that it ends on input[2] innstead of input[1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to type the password in the field you've selected. As you've noted in the comments, the xpath switches from `input[1]` to `input[2]`. The latter is where you're supposed to put the password. I don't understand the mechanism by which the xpath changes when you try to send keys there, but it does. Depending on how quickly it changes, anything from 0 to a few characters will be sent to the wrong input, which explains why the password field ends up with a substring of your password.

From the html, we can see there are 3 input fields, all belonging to the class `'hm-Login_InputField'`.

```
<div class="hm-Login ">
    <div class="hm-Login_UserNameWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText " style="">
            Registrarse
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hm-Login_PasswordWrapper ">
        <input type="text" class="hm-Login_InputField Hidden ">
        <input type="password" class="hm-Login_InputField ">
        <button tabindex="0" class="hm-Login_LoginBtn ">
            IR
        </button>
        <div class="hm-Login_InputText ">
            Recordar contraseña
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you collect them all, from top to bottom, they are the username, the field you tried to put the password in and the password field.

Now, if you try to send the keys directly to the password field, `input[2]`, you will get an error that the element is not visible. You have to first click on `input[1]` in order to make `input[2]` visible.

You can easily do it with xpaths, but I find the following approach cleaner.

```
login = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'hm-Login')))

fields = login.find_elements_by_css_selector('.hm-Login_InputField')
button = login.find_element_by_css_selector('.hm-Login_LoginBtn')

fields[0].send_keys('user_name')
fields[1].click()
fields[2].send_keys('password')
button.click()
```

Comment: That fully answer and solve my problem. I ticked your answer as the right one. By the way, why you consider cleaner using css selector instead of xpath?

Comment: @puppet [All methods to find an element have their uses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620562/is-using-absolute-xpath-to-locate-elements-a-good-practice-if-no-is-there-any), but in this case finding something by its class name or css selector is more compact, because you can get all fields with one search. Also, if someone wanted to check the correctness of the xpath, they'd have to manually transverse the tree, which is tedious in this case. However, a relative xpath from the `login` object isn't bad at all.

Comment: @puppet [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521441/locating-an-element-by-id) is also an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I first click in the element then I send the text, it solved the problem.

```
    el_search_wo.driver = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='arid_WIN_0_302258625']")
    el_search_wo.click()
    el_search_wo.send_keys('TEXT HERE')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had found a solution by ActionChains, but it doesn't work anymore:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(user, 'my_user').perform()
ActionChains(driver).send_keys_to_element(passw, 'password').perform()
```

**Recently I found a new way**  to interact with inputs to insert numerous characters (more than 200chars) and **it worked perfectly**.

Some websites or applications might be relying on **JavaScript events** for input handling, and Selenium is not triggering these events because of "typing too fast". You can use it instead:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'my_user';", user)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'password';", passw)
```