# How to click on checkbox on webpage using selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium, firefox, web-scraping

I have a query,how to click on checkbox on webpage using selenium vba.

Below is the screen shot where i want to click

[image]

Below is the html code.

```html
<span name="locSpans[]" value="Nerul" style="display:block">
<input type="checkbox" name="locArr[]" value="8897" onclick="enableDisableLocality(); showSelectedLoc();">Nerul
<br>
<input type="hidden" name="locArrVal[]" disabled="disabled" value="Nerul">
</span>
```

Comment: Where is your initial approach that didn't work?

Comment: I try like this but not working-driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[contains(@name,'locArr[]')][contains(text(),'Nerul')]").Click

Comment: Its not working i am getting error-Run time error'11' element not visible error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use xpath below to get checkbox, it means: find input with type="checkbox" and parent SPAN with text "Nerul".

```
driver.FindElementByXPath("//input[ancestor::span[normalize-space(.)='Nerul'] and @type='checkbox']").Click
```

Answer (score 3):

**`FindElementByCss` is generally faster unless using IE, and then it depends which version of IE and what type of traversal is required.**

Repeated tests have proven `FindElementByCss` to be more performant than `FindElementByXPath` (Note: that if there is a unique id present then selecting by id is always the first choice!)

In [benchmarked tests](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2) `Chrome` and `FireFox` saw faster matching using CSS consistently across different traversal paths. They are optimized with CSS in mind and using CSS selectors is advocated as [selenium best practice](https://vimeo.com/44133409). `IE` was more variable with most instances of `XPath` being slightly more performant, but there being some clear paths that favoured `CSS` selection.  Long XPath selectors will be costly and prone to breakage. Later versions of `IE` saw more variability. `Opera12` browser came in with mixed results.

---

**I would use a CSS selector:**

So, for a simple selection based on likely unique attribute, I would go with an attribute CSS selector of `[value='8897']` to target the `value` attribute. The `[]` means attribute selector.  So `value` attribute with value of `8897`.

```
driver.FindElementByCss("[value='8897']").Click
```

If you want to be more selective you can throw in an additional attribute selector, as follows, to target the `type` attribute.

```
driver.FindElementByCss("[type=checkbox][value='8897']").Click
```

---

**When should I use XPath then?**

Older IE versions for sure.

Any requirement for *walking up* the DOM would point to XPath usage.

XPath has some great additional locator strategies for hard to find elements, but that is not necessary AFAIK here. You can see some of the additional considerations [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41001439/what-is-the-most-efficient-selector-to-use-with-findelement).

Answer (score -1):

Try this if not go for CSS Selector Option

```
bot.Window.Maximize

bot.FindElementByName("locArrVal").Click

bot.Wait 1000
```