# how to get unique XPATH for buttons when the features for all input are the same

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract NBA players stats using selenium web driver in python and here is my attempt:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get('https://www.basketball-reference.com')

xp_1 = "//select[@id='selector_0' and @name='team_val']"
team = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(xp_1))
team.select_by_visible_text('Golden State Warriors')

xp_2 = "//select[@id='selector_0' and @name='1']"
player = Select(browser.find_element_by_xpath(xp_2))
player.select_by_visible_text('Jordan Bell')
```

The problem I have is there are 4 "Go" buttons in this page and all have the same input features.  In other words, the following xpath returns 4 buttons:

```
//input[@type='submit'and @name="go_button" and @id="go_button" and @value="Go!"]
```

I unsuccessfully tried adding ancestor as below but it does not return an xpath:

```
//input[@type='submit' and @name="go_button" and @id="go_button" and @value="Go!"]/ancestor::/form[@id='player_roster']
```

I appreciate any insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPAth to select required Go button:

```
"//input[@value='Go!' and ancestor::form[@id='player_roster']]"
```

or

```
"//form[@id='player_roster']//input[@value='Go!']"
```

Note that you shouldn't mix single and double quotes in a XPath expression and correct usage of `ancestor` axis is

```
//descendant_node/ancestor::ancestor_node
```

Comment: @Andersson-Thanks and sorry for my mistake in using ancestor; I am just learning selenium

Answer (score 1):

You could also switch to CSS selectors and use a descendant combination where you use an parent element to restrict to the appropriate form with `Go` button

```
#player_roster #go_button
```

That is

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#player_roster #go_button")
```

The # is an id selector.

CSS selectors are generally faster than XPath, except in cases of older IE versions. More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039249/6241235).

Comment: @QHarr-thanks for the suggestion.  What are the pros/cons of CSS selector over xpath?

Comment: The CSS selector is faster than XPath in most instances and generally more robust. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039249/6241235