# VBA Selenium Click on input type="radio"

Tags: excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the Verification Successful but not being able to name or ID.

```html
<span class="gwt-RadioButton GDQHEYCCEBC GDQHEYCCEV"><input type="radio" name="gwt-uid-482" value="on" id="gwt-uid-553" tabindex="0" checked=""><label for="gwt-uid-553">Verification successful</label></span>
<input type="radio" name="gwt-uid-482" value="on" id="gwt-uid-553" tabindex="0" checked="">
```

[Verification Successful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTLlG.png)

below are the codes I've tried.

```html
 driver.FindElementByTag("gwt-uid-240").Click
 
  driver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span[1]/input").Click
```

Appreciate any assistance.

Comment: what happened with your code? Did you look at attribute selector? [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52039249/6241235)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply QHarr. 
I've managed to select the first value but still not clicking into it. below is the code I've tried. I just don't know how to add the checked=""><label for="gwt-uid-553">Verification successful</label></span>

driver.FindElementByCss("[type=checkbox][value='8897']").Click

Comment: the html in the question has [type="radio"]  and  [value="on"]