# How to find if the element as a icon(camera) without specific locators in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Difficult to find an element of icons like camera

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"app\"]")).click();
```

xpath is changed every time

Comment: But id I guess not. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521441/locating-an-element-by-id

Comment: Please post the html structure of webElement