# For dynamically changing elements, which locator has a higher cross-browser reliability rate and why: cssSelector or Xpath?

Tags: java, eclipse, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

There has a cold war between cssSelector and Xpath locating strategies as to which is more cross-browser friendly. To make matters worse, I have read varied opinions as to which is more reliable in the handling of dynamic web elements across browsers. I have not been in the game long enough to make a distinct comparison and declare one of them a winner. For the experts on the subject, can you please share your thoughts from a selenium webdriver point of view?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your question is probably answered here [stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?rq=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?rq=1) with over 40 upvotes as of Oct 2016 it is probably a reliable answer.