# How to identify an element using webdriver in python for http link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, click

How to identify the link, I have inspected the elements which are as below :

```
<div class="vmKOT" role="navigation">
<a class="Ml68il" href="https://www.google.com" aria-label="Search" data-track-as="Welcome Header Search"></a>
<a class="WaidDw" href="https://mail.google.com" aria-label="Mail" data-track-as="Welcome Header Mail"></a>
<a class="a4KP9d" href="https://maps.google.com" aria-label="Maps" data-track-as="Welcome Header Maps"></a>
<a class="QJOPee" href="https://www.youtube.com" aria-label="YouTube" data-track-as="Welcome Header YouTube"></a>
</div>
```

I want to identify the class `WaidDw` or `href` and `click` it using `python`.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. Did you forget to add something or accidentally removed something?

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('WaidDw').click()
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="https://mail.google.com" and @aria-label="Mail"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your provided HTML all attribute's values are unique, you can locate easily that element by using their attribute value.

As your question points to locate this `<a class="WaidDw" href="https://mail.google.com" aria-label="Mail" data-track-as="Welcome Header Mail"></a>` element. I'm providing you multiple `cssSelectors` which can work easily to identify the same element as below :-

- `a.WaidDw`
- `a.WaidDw[href='https://mail.google.com']`
- `a.WaidDw[aria-label='Mail']`
- `a.WaidDw[data-track-as='Welcome Header Mail']`
- `a.WaidDw[href='https://mail.google.com'][aria-label='Mail']`
- `a.WaidDw[href='https://mail.google.com'][aria-label='Mail'][data-track-as='Welcome Header Mail']`

---

**Note :-** Keep in practice (priority) to use `cssSelector` instead `xpath` if possible, because [`cssSelectors` perform far better than `xpath`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t)

---

[Locating Element by CSS Selectors using python](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors) :-

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('use any one of the given above css selector')
```

[Clicks the element :-](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.click)

```
element.click()
```

---

**Reference link :-**

- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors