# Can't inspect search button in IntelliJ-selenium Chrome driver

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on automation testing website www.benjerry.com/.
I can't inspect serch button.
I succesfully enter credential in search field, but can't click on search button.
I try all kind of combinations, but still nothing.
Can someone please help me?

[image: 1]

Picture with marked problem

Code line:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.btn-submit")).click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already accepted the answer given from @**kushal**. I'd like to highlight some points that could be useful in your **Automation** Journey .

You can use this **cssSelector :** `input[id='searchTerm'] ~button>span`

your code would like this :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[id='searchTerm'] ~button>span")).click();
```

Here are some benefits of using this **cssSelector** :

1. cssSelector are more **consistent** than Xpath.
2. Xpath Provided by Kushal contains **numeric** that is **[2]**, which is never gonna be **consistent** , your test may fail if Dev would put **one more span** inside **Button** Tag. So in case if you still want to go with **Xpath** , then your Xpath should look like this  :

   //input[@id='searchTerm']/following-sibling::button/span

You can find the difference between **cssSelector** and **Xpath** here :

[What is the difference between css-selector & Xpath? which is better(according to performance & for cross browser testing)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice and sugestion.

Comment: Glad ! I could help ! Cheers mate !

Answer (score 0):

Try following line of code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button/span[contains(.,'Search')])[2]")).click();
```

Comment: I am new at automatisation, can u explain me please, how did U solve that problem or just to tell me what kind of litereture should i read, so that i can solve that situation by myselfe next time? I would like to do it by myselfe next time:)

Comment: go through this article here: https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html and search for XPATH and XPATH AXES tutorials on google