# Selenium FindElement by parent div

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to find link element of "a href". Snippet code:

```
<div id="contact-link">
    <a href="http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact" title="Contact Us">Contact us</a>
</div>
```

I managed doing it by:

1. `Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@title='Contact Us']")).Click();`

2.`Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=contact']")).Click();`

3.`Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Contact us']")).Click();`

Could someone tell me how can I get by firstly getting **parent div** and then find what's inside that div (by going from the top to the bottom)

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by **how can I get by firstly getting parent div and then find what's inside**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically, with xpath, you are looking to replicate the HTML structure. What you need is:

```
//div[@id='contact-link']/a
```

This is going to return the a href under the div. Assuming its just 1, thats the way to go. If you want to go a little further, try:

```
//div[@id='contact-link']/a[@title='Contact Us']
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you have already accepted the answer , I would like to highlight some point about Xpath and cssSelector. You should always pick **cssSelector** over **Xpath** :

Here is **cssSelector** for your requirement:

```
div[id='contact-link']>a
```

**Code :**

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div[id='contact-link']>a")).Click();
```

For more about cssSelector :  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp
For Difference between Xpath and cssSelector, you can read it from this **SO** post: [Diff between Xpath and cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: No problem @Ixi11 :)