# Unable to locate send button in whatsapp api

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

I am trying to send a message through web whatsapp using python selenium.

here is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
browser=webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("""https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=************&text=I'm%20interested%20in%20your%20car%20for%20sale""")
time.sleep(5)
send_btn=browser.find_element_by_id("action-button")
send_btn.click()
```

[image: this is the send button]
It is not clicking the send button, it just blinks. please help.

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: No, but now I fixed it by `find_by_xpath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned, you are using **XPATH** , I would suggest you to use **CSS_SELECTOR** over **XPATH**.

This is the code you can try out :

```
send_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a.button.button--simple.button--primary')
send_button.click()
```

**UPDATE :**
CSS selectors perform far better than Xpath and it is well documented in Selenium community. Here are some reasons,

1. Xpath engines are different in each browser, hence make them inconsistent.
2. IE does not have a native xpath engine, therefore selenium injects its own xpath engine for compatibility of its API. Hence we lose the advantage of using native browser features that WebDriver inherently promotes.

For more you refer this **SO** Link :  [XPATH VS CSS_SELECTOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Okay I will try this.. but What advantage in using CSS selector?

Comment: Thanks for the detail. I will modify with your code. Can we send images like this using WhatsApp API?

Comment: if you can manually do it , you can automate it. I haven't used whatsapp api though.

Comment: Yes I can automate it with selenium by finding xpath of the respected contact name but I am trying to send with the phone numbers not with contact names

Comment: Don't go for xpath firstly , use id , classname , tag name , link text, partial link text , css selector then if nothing works out for you , xpath comes to floor.

Comment: Ya that's fine.. my problem is to send images to phone numbers which are not saved in my contacts

Comment: Can you send images to phone numbers which aren't saved in your contact manually ? I don't think so

Comment: But we can send texts to phone numbers which are not saved using the above WhatsApp API. It's ok leave it. We will find another way