# How to click on Load More button within Google Trends and print all the titles through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, lazy-loading

this time I would like to click a button in order to load more real-time searches. Here is the link of the website:

https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all

The button is located at the end of the page and it has the following code:

```
<div class="feed-load-more-button" ng-if="ctrl.shouldShowLoadingMoreItemsSpinner()" ng-click="ctrl.loadMoreFeedItems()" role="button" tabindex="0" style="">
Load more
</div>
```

Since theres some AngularJS involved I cant figure out how to do it...
Any tips/help?

Thank you guys,
Joan

Comment: just find it and click on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click on `LOAD MORE` button to load more real-time searches and then to print them you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/realtime?geo=AR&category=all")
  myLength = len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='title']"))))

  while True:
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
      try:
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='feed-load-more-button'][@ng-click=\"ctrl.loadMoreFeedItems()\"]"))).click()
          WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']")) > myLength)
          titles = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='title']")
          myLength = len(titles)
      except TimeoutException:
          break

  for title in titles:
      print(title.text)
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Nikola Kalinic • 2018 World Cup • Zlatko Dalic
  Vicentico • Valeria Bertuccelli • Florián Fernandez Capello
  Mauricio Macri • Juan José Aranguren • Argentina • Jorge Lanata
  Goalkeeper • 2018 World Cup • Mohamed El-Shenawy • Ahmed El-Shenawy
  Argentina • Manuel Belgrano • María Josefa Ezcurra • Mercedes Tomasa de San Martín y Escalada
  South Korea national football team • Russia • Zlatan Ibrahimovic
  Italian nationality law • Mar del Plata
  Hirving Lozano • 2018 World Cup • Earthquake
  Central Bank of Argentina • Luis Caputo • Federico Sturzenegger • Nicolás Dujovne
  Porsche Mission E • Electric vehicle • Car • Electric car
  Intelligence • Intelligence quotient • Research
  Call for bids • National Flag Memorial • Monument • Rosario • Pablo Javkin
  Journalist • Club Atlético Belgrano • Córdoba • Manuel Belgrano
  France • Spain • Immigration
  Natti Natasha • Zum Zum • Daddy Yankee • R.K.M & Ken-Y • Francisco José Arcángel Ramos
  Mercosur • Pacific Alliance • Pact • Paraguay
  World Cup • England national football team • Romelu Lukaku • Dries Mertens
  House arrest • Detention • Robbery
  Argentina • Emerging markets • MSCI • Market • Finance • Morgan Stanley
  Eurozone • Budget • France • Bruno Le Maire • Germany • Finance
  Intelligence • Intelligence quotient • Research
  Brazil national football team • Tite • Philippe Coutinho • Rostov Arena
  2018 World Cup • Aleksandar Kolarov • Guillermo Ochoa
  2018 World Cup • Spain
  Sloth • Giant ground sloth • Fossil • San Pedro
  Government • Inflation • Alfredo Cornejo • Mendoza • Ministry of Finance
  Corrientes • Cannabis • Tractor • Argentine Naval Prefecture
  Argentine Chamber of Deputies • Chubut Province • Peronism • Front for Victory
  Jorge Rial • Father's Day • Intrusos en el espectáculo
  Debt • Debt relief • Refinancing • Chaco Province
  Polygraph
  Malaria • Paraguay • Americas
  General Confederation of Labour • Unemployment • Trade union
  Earthquake • Japan
  Angela Merkel • Europe • Germany • Emmanuel Macron • European Union
  Colombia • Ivan Duque • Gustavo Petro
  Lynx • Wildcat • Cat
  Rafael Márquez • 2018 World Cup • Antonio Carbajal
  Superior Council for Private Enterprise • Nicaraguan Social Security Institute
  2018 World Cup • William Kvist • Jefferson Farfán
  La Plata • Controlled-access highway • Buenos Aires Province • Ensenada
  Leonardo Mayer • Kevin Anderson • ATP World Tour 500 series • Association of Tennis Professionals
  Cristiano Ronaldo • 2018 World Cup • Spain
  Casino • Mendoza • Hyatt
  Mauricio Macri • Jorge Lanata • Argentina • Alejandro Wiebe
  Drug
  Buenos Aires Province • Judiciary
  2018 World Cup • Lionel Messi • Russia • Diego Maradona • Mario Kempes
  Santiago • Natural environment • Air pollution
  Chimbas Department
  Chaco Province • Judiciary • Unemployment
  Hailey Rhode Baldwin • Justin Bieber
  2018 World Cup • Russia
  Mauricio Macri • Luis Caputo • Politician • Argentine Chamber of Deputies
  Trade war • Agriculture • Donald Trump • China
  2018 World Cup • Dennis te Kloese • Juan Carlos Osorio
  Aaron Ramsey • 2018 World Cup • Arsenal F.C. • Football player • Gareth Bale
  2018 World Cup • Aleksandar Kolarov
  Iñaki Urdangarin • Cristina Federica, Infanta of Spain • Spain • Luis Roldán
  Argentina • Electric car
  San Lorenzo de Almagro • Liga Nacional de Básquet • Corrientes
  Christina Aguilera • Jimmy Fallon • Liberation • New York City
  Intelligence quotient • Intelligence • Flynn effect • Research
  María Eugenia Vidal • Republican Proposal • Horacio Rodríguez Larreta
  Natural environment • Pollution • Plastic pollution
  Funding • International Finance Corporation • World Bank • Córdoba
  Face • Zygomatic bone • Rosario
  Cristóbal López • Administración Federal de Ingresos Públicos • Ricardo Echegaray
  Club Atlético Belgrano • Lucas Bernardi • Superliga Argentina de Fútbol
  Juan José Aranguren • Mauricio Macri • Energy • YPF
  Greater Buenos Aires • Motor coach
  Stranger Things • MTV Movie & TV Awards
  Peru • Lima • Earthquake • 2018 World Cup • Geophysics Institute of Peru
  Juan Carlos Osorio • 2018 World Cup
  2018 World Cup • Player • Russia • Lionel Messi
  Raffaella Carrà
  America's Got Talent • Janis Joplin • Howie Mandel
  Homicide • Detention
  La Plata • Julio Garro • Víctor Manuel Fernández • María Eugenia Vidal
  Mariano Arcioni • Chubut Province • Payment
  Angela Merkel • Horst Seehofer • Germany • Government • Human migration
  Israel • Benjamin Netanyahu • Syria • Iran • Ali Khamenei • Vladimir Putin
  Yerba mate • Cannabis • Lomas de Zamora • Detention • Mate
  Senate • Argentine Chamber of Deputies
  2010 FIFA World Cup • South Africa
  Handball • Chile • Argentina national football team
  2018 World Cup • Russia • Terrorism • Attack
  Abortion • Conscientious objector
  Rosario • Trade
  Natalie Weber • Mauro Zárate • Pampita
  Water • Cipolletti • Pressure • Cleaning
  Chimbas
  NATO • Military exercise • Russia
  Federico Sturzenegger • Economist • Argentina • Arnaldo Bocco • Martín Redrado
  Nolle prosequi
  2018 World Cup • Russia • Paolo Guerrero • Christian Cueva
  Ricardo Darín • Valeria Bertuccelli • Érica Rivas
  Joachim Löw • 2018 World Cup
  Israel • Golan Heights • Syria • Donald Trump
  Meningitis • Bacteria • Salta • Streptococcus pneumoniae
  ANSES • Subsidy
  Argentine Chamber of Deputies • Radical Civic Union • Cambiemos •
  Martín Demichelis • 2018 World Cup • Russia
  Santiago de Compostela • Pilgrim • Galicia • Spain
  Refugee • Pope Francis • Human migration
  Stranger Things • Father's Day • Joe Keery
  Ivan Duque • President of Colombia • Latin America
  General Confederation of Labour • Unemployment • General strike • Buenos Aires Province
  Juan Carlos Osorio • Faustino Asprilla • 2018 World Cup
  Germán Burgos • Club Atlético River Plate • Diego Simeone • Atlético Madrid
  Nissan Navara • Pickup truck • Automotive industry
  Baobab • Research • Tree
  Susana Giménez • Alejandro Wiebe • Argentina • Telefe
  Wanda Nara • Maxi López • Mauro Icardi
  Damir Skomina • 2018 World Cup • Colombia • Referee • Russia • Mehdi Abid Charef
  Diabetes mellitus • Visual perception • Diabetic retinopathy
  Berisso • Threat • La Plata • Search and seizure • School
  Game of Thrones • HBO • San Diego Comic-Con • Spin-off • George R. R. Martin
  Argentina • Duet • Traveling Wilburys
  Blood donation • Uruguay • Maldonado
  2018 World Cup Group F • Mexico • Hirving Lozano
  Colombian presidential election, 2018 • Colombia • Juan Manuel Santos
  Colombia national football team
  Desertification • United Nations Convention to Combat Desertification
  Saski Baskonia • Liga ACB • Pablo Laso • Real Madrid C.F.
  Rosario de la Frontera • Salta • Spa town
  Neymar • 2018 World Cup • Philippe Coutinho • Tite • Russia
  Pocito Department
  Argentine peso • Depreciation • Central Bank of Argentina
  San Salvador de Jujuy • Buenos Aires International Book Fair • Fair •
  Córdoba • Shock
  Iceland • Immigration • Icelanders
  Mirtha Legrand
  Traffic collision • Wound
  2018 World Cup • Russia • Vikings
  Mauricio Macri • Businessperson • Argentina • Economic development
  Ricardo Darín • Valeria Bertuccelli • Érica Rivas • Vicentico
  María Eugenia Vidal • Martiniano Molina • Quilmes
  Argentina women's national field hockey team • Julieta Jankunas • Argentina
  Prince Harry • Catherine, Duchess of Cambridge • British royal family
  Sergej Milinkovic-Savic • SS Lazio • 2018 World Cup
  Organ donation • Organ • Organ transplantation
  Sex education • San Fernando del Valle de Catamarca • Argentine Chamber of Deputies
  Margarita Stolbizer • Sergio Massa • Peronism • Justicialist Party • Elisa Carrió
  Google Maps • Waze • Information • Radar
  Locomotive • Japan
  Spain • Human migration • Immigration • France • Valencia • Carmen Calvo Poyato
  Joaquín Sabina • Madrid
  Jorge Lorenzo • Marc Márquez • MotoGP • Dani Pedrosa
  Manuel Belgrano
  2018 World Cup • Russia • Mohamed Salah • Denis Cheryshev
  María Eugenia Vidal • Teacher
  Remand
  Magistrate • Judiciary • Research
  Laura Bush • Donald Trump • Immigration • George W. Bush • Melania Trump
  Sebastián Piñera • Chile • Michelle Bachelet
  School • Gender identity • Discrimination • National Institute Against Discrimination, Xenophobia and Racism
  Engineering • San Miguel de Tucumán
  School • Buenos Aires Province • Tariff
  Edgardo Bauza • Rosario Central • Marco Ruben • Rosario
  Bicameralism
  Russia • 2018 World Cup • Lionel Messi
  Rawson Department, San Juan
  El Litoral • Corrientes Province
  Abortion • PH: Podemos hablar • Andy Kusnetzoff • Charlotte Caniggia
  The Shining • Ewan McGregor • Doctor Sleep • Danny Torrance • Stephen King
  Paulo Ferrari • Rosario Central • Rosario • Superliga Argentina de Fútbol
  Carbon monoxide
  Ground frost • Fog • Rain and snow mixed • Cold • Posadas
  Argentine rock • Russia • Luis Alberto Spinetta • Gustavo Cerati • Charly García
  Incredibles 2 • Brad Bird • Pixar
  Carbohydrate • Dieting • Weight loss
  Uber • Mendoza Province • Government • System • Statute
  Paragliding
  Jorge Sampaoli • Pedro Pasculli • 2018 World Cup • Paulo Dybala • Russia
  Posadas • Cold
  Luis Miguel • Mexico
  Unidentified flying object • Russia • Phenomenon
  Lisandro Magallán • Boca Juniors • AFC Ajax • Wílmar Barrios
  Tandil • Fossil • Glyptodon
  Harry Kane • 2018 World Cup • Gareth Southgate
  Light welterweight • Boxing • Almirante Brown Partido • Mariano Cascallares
  New Jersey
  Small and medium-sized enterprises • Argentina • CAME - Argentina Confederation of Medium Enterprises
  Season • Ryan Murphy • American Horror Story: Murder House • Sarah Paulson
  Conflagration • Posadas
  Robot • Old age • China
  2018 World Cup • Russia • Terrorism • Islamic State of Iraq and the Levant
  Christian Cueva • 2018 World Cup
  Argentina national football team • Volleyball • Argentina
  National Electoral Institute • Candidate • National Action Party • Mexico
  Horoscope • Astrological sign
  Mauricio Macri • María Eugenia Vidal • Ensenada • Ambulance • Cambiemos
  Trade • Tax deduction • Debt • Macroeconomics
  Cristiano Ronaldo • Pelé • 2018 World Cup • Miroslav Klose • Uwe Seeler
  Martín Miguel de Güemes • Juan Manuel Urtubey • Salta Province • Argentina
  Compressed natural gas • La Pampa Province • General Pico • Camuzzi Gas Pampeana
  Santa Fe • Provincial Hospital Dr. José María Cullen • Baleada
  National University of La Plata • Vocational school • School • Vocational education
  ```

Comment: this is awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

for scrolling down you can use this code :

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

where Y : is the vertical position you want to scroll to.(you can provide the value of Y as 100,200,300 as per your requirement).

Once scroll down is done, you can use this code :

```
load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-click='ctrl.loadMoreFeedItems()']")))  
load_more_button.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

Find it with `find_elements_by_css_selector` and click on it. I don't think if you need to wait or scroll.

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[ng-click=\"ctrl.loadMoreFeedItems()\"]")
element.click()
```

---

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), if you wonder why I have not used `xPath`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(webdriver, 10)
load_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'feed-load-more-button']")))
load_button.click()
```