# what's the fastest way to web-scraping and get different items from a website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, request

I've been working on a web-scraping project written in Python using Selenium and requests. Each time when I need data I send a request to get it (or using Selenium) and each request takes time.

My question is, is there any option to get a lot of different data ( such as product's name+price+shipping) in 1 request in Python or even in javascript?

Given a url for example: [https://www.amazon.com/Dell-Inspiron-7573-i7-8550U-Windows/dp/B07NRC8ZXC/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=laptop+i7&qid=1572590892&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyNjFPSFdTOEpVODdQJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwNTU5Nzk1MlBGWFkxU0JKOVlLNiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwNjU0MzYwM0NRT01ER1oxSDdMOCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07NRC8ZXC)

NOTE: you marked this question as duplicated with this question - [How to click on Load More button within Google Trends and print all the titles through Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908744/how-to-click-on-load-more-button-within-google-trends-and-print-all-the-titles-t)
PLEASE, those are different questions, I'm asking about getting this product's price+name+shipping who are under different "scopes", she asked about getting the same "objects" (such as names)!!!
so if you know any other way to get those things instead of sending 3 different requests to get them, I would love to hear about them...  I've heard that there is a way to combine a few requests as one big request in javascript, is it true?

Answer (score 0):

still i'm waiting for an answer, anyone?