# Unable to key text in text box with Selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Given that this is the element of the text box (Got this from Chrome inspect element https://www.mousehuntgame.com/login.php):

```
<input name="username" class="username" type="text" placeholder="Enter 
your username" onkeyup="app.pages.LoginPage.checkEnter(event, 'login');">
```

I am trying to input some text into the input box. I searched for the element by name, and used send_keys() to input some text into the text box

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem.send_keys("aa")
```

I receive an exception:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable
```

I suspect i am not using find_element_by correctly. Where am I going wrong?

Additionally: Is there a way to tell in Chrome what I have selected from a find_element_by method? Is there some sort of method to highlight in the browser, the thing I have selected with my find_element_by method?

Comment: Try to wait for [visibility of element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). Also check whether there is only one input with `"username"` name: `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_name("username")))`

Comment: @Gen Tan please upload the url of apge and full error log for the same.

Comment: @Andersson There was indeed more than 1 input with "username" name. How should I define my element more accurately since there is more than 1 input with "username"? Is there anyway to use `driver.find_elements_by_name("username")[0]` as an input?

Comment: @HimanshuPoddar added URL of page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two forms: first for Registration, second - for LogIn... Both have same input field with name `"username"`

You can use below CSS-selector to select input field in required form:

```
user_input_register = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.register input[name='username']")
user_input_login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.login input[name='username']")
```

Or you can define forms for further input fields handling:

```
register = driver.find_element_by_class_name('register')
login = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login')

username_register = register.find_element_by_name('username')
username_login = login.find_element_by_name('username')
```

Comment: Opss... didn't see your answer... for some reason, I found it easier to use XPath can you tell me what is the advantage of css_selector?

Comment: @MosheSlavin , in this current case `"div.register input[name='username']"` is just shorter :) XPath for the same will look like `//div[contains(@class, "register")]//input[@name="username"]`

Comment: Ok so it doesn't mean it will take longer to locate or that xpath is less robust...

Comment: @MosheSlavin , well [CSS seem to be faster than XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t), but I'm not sure that you really can see that difference in performance. As for me XPath is more flexible and powerful, so I mostly use XPath

Comment: Thanks for the ref. I'll take a look and thanks again for your time!

Comment: May I ask how you derived the arguments for css_selector? Am i able to find it from chrome -> inspect -> elements?

Comment: @GenTan , Yes, I got them by inspecting element in dev tools... You just need to use unique attributes that will match required elements only and avoid matching something else

Answer (score 1):

As @Andersson commented you have more than one element with `"username"`.

You should use a more specific XPath such as:

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@placeholder="Enter 
your username"]')`

Or

`elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="username" and @type="text"]')`

Answer (score 1):

To send a character sequence to the *username* field with *placeholder* text as **Enter your username**, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.username[name='username'][placeholder='Enter your username']"))).send_keys("Gen Tan")
  ```