# How to extract the text of the outer span using Selenium WebDriver and Java

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm facing a problem, where I'm unable to get the text of a span tag that has another span tag as a child:

```
<span class="abc">
        <span class="def">Inner Span</span> 
        Outer Span
</span>
```

When I'm using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".abc")).getText()
```

Selenium returns "Inner Span" as well as "Outer Span". I guess innerText is used here. But I only need the text "Outer Span" of the outer span with the class "abc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text **Outer Span** is a *Text Node* and is the **lastChild** of the parent `<span>` node. So extract the text you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.abc")))).toString());
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  System.out.println(((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='abc']")))).toString());
  ```

Comment: Great solution for non-straightforward issue. And awesome example of leveraging javascript and java in tangent.

Comment: You have posted the same answer as mine.

Comment: @KunduK Not sure why you felt _...posted the same answer as mine..._. However, here are the differences: 1) Your answer doesn't contains anything related to [**cssSelector**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-cssselector-xpath-and-which-is-better-with-resp/54606452#54606452). 2) Your answer speaks about `getAttribute()` and `split()` which have no place within my answer. 3) You are **forcefully** **`typecasting`** through `(String)` where as I have used the much **proven** and **efficient** `toString()`. Let me know if you have any questions/doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try `JavascriptExecutor` and get the `textContent` of `lastChild`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibilityOfElementLocated`()

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='abc']")));
JavascriptExecutor js= (JavascriptExecutor) driver; 
String strtext=(String) js.executeScript("return arguments[0].lastChild.textContent;", element);
System.out.println(strtext.trim());
```

---

Or you can split lines and get the desire value using Index.

```
WebElement element = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='abc']")));
String text=element.getAttribute("textContent");
String[] lines = text.split("\\r?\\n");
System.out.println(lines[2].trim());
```