# How to extract the text "152" from the textnode using Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, textnode

[image]

I need to extract the xpath for the number 152. The xpath that I created extracts the text after 152 which is "Test" but excludes the number 152. I need to get this count.

I am using below xpath :

```
//div\[@class='filter_filter__5H_fi'\]/h1
```

Not sure how to get this.

Comment: Tag your binding language, please. Also `"152"` is a text node, you cannot parse `.text()[1]` within selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML:

[image: HTML]

both the text ***152*** and ***Test*** are within their respective [text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59698152/7429447).

---

### Solution

To retrive the text ***152*** you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using [*Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436337/7429447), *cssSelector* and *`firstChild`*:

  ```
  WebElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.filter_filter__5H_fi > h1"));
  System.out.println(((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;", element).toString());
  ```
- Using [*Python*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63155068/7429447), *xpath* and *`firstChild`*:

  ```
  parent_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='filter_filter__5H_fi']/h1")
  print(driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', parent_element).strip())
  ```

Comment: I tried using "//div[@class='filter_filter__5H_fi']/h1/text()[1]" but it throws error : "The result of this xpath is an Object.text, it should be an element."

Comment: I didn't either suggested that. Just copy paste the lines of code and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks. I tried running the first code but it still returns only the second element " Test".

Comment: My bad, there was a typo which I have fixed now. Let me know the status.

Comment: That worked !!! thanks a lot ! Can this only be achieved by using javascript executor ? Cant we have a straight xpath for this ? Let me know.

Comment: @NileshAmbestha You can do do it with a css/xpath, but definitely that's going to be complex one. Using _javascript executor_ is the ideal and easiest approach in case of text nodes.