# Python Selenium - get element by relative xpath

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the "10 Year Australian bond" prices table on this website:
https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-derivatives-market/derivatives-market-prices/bond-derivatives

The following code works fine:

```
url='https://www2.asx.com.au/markets/trade-our-derivatives-market/derivatives-market-prices/bond-derivatives'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
id='onetrust-accept-btn-handler'
driver.find_element_by_id(id).click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
id='tab-panel_17'
time.sleep(2)
tbl = driver.find_element_by_id(id).get_attribute('outerHTML')
soup = BeautifulSoup(tbl, 'html.parser')
aus_10y_future = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
```

In order to click on the "10 Year Australian bond" tab, I tried to use relative xpath insted of absolute one.
[image]

So, insted of

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[3]').click()
```

I tried:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class_name,"cmp-tabs__tabtitle")]/li[3]').click()
```

but I get an error. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_name` is not a valid element attribute. It should be `class`.
Also I see you are using wrong element.
This should work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[contains(@class,'cmp-tabs__tablist')]//li[3]").click()
```

Answer (score 1):

A css selector is far better locator than xpath, You can read about it more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-cssselector-xpath-and-which-is-better-with-resp)

You can furthur use this `css_selector` :

```
li[data-f2-context-code='XT']
```

in code :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[data-f2-context-code='XT']").click()
```

or if you can construct a way better **xpath** like this :

```
//li[@data-f2-context-code='XT']
```

and use it like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//li[@data-f2-context-code='XT']").click()
```

Comment: I'm a newbie so I wasn't aware of css_selector. Performance differences are not an issue for me (my web scraping activity is very light) but it's good to have another tool. Thanks