# How to use XPATH function with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am very new to Python and am trying to search numbers in the search bar of a website, click submit and then clear the search bar and repeat for all the values in the code. However I keep getting an error saying WebDriverException: Message: To submit an element, it must be nested inside a form element and I have no idea what this means! Other errors I have gotten have said AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath.' Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried changing where the 'xpath' is either inside or outside the brackets but get the first error when its inside and the second error when its outside. The "//input...." is what I got when I inspected the search bar on the website.

```
def automate_website():
    # Initialize the Chrome webdriver with options
    service = Service(chromedriver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    
    # Open the website
    driver.get("https://www.business.qld.gov.au/industries/mining-energy-water/water/bores-and-groundwater/bore-reports")
    
    # Locate the search input field
    search_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='text' and @class='form-control form-group']")
```

Comment: Why use xpath here, though? Why not use a normal query selector since you're loading a webpage, not an XML deocument? `id` attributes are unique, so just query for `#text.form-control.form-group`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. For your information why use XPath with Selenium see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50292127/3710053. It's correct that a `id` attribute is unique, so the css `#text` is enough.

Comment: Your XPath seems to ben correct. Although `//input[@id='text']` should do the job as well, since  `id` attribute is unique. So something else is wrong

Comment: Why would `#text` be enough? The id is unique, but that doesn't mean it's the right element in terms of "what role it plays on the page" yet until the additional classes have been added to it. (so that's something "user23493265" will have to comment on)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Selenium [Explicit Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) may help. Refer code below:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.business.qld.gov.au/industries/mining-energy-water/water/bores-and-groundwater/bore-reports')

# Create a wait object with 10s wait time
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

# Locate the search input field and enter keys
search_box = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "text")))
search_box.send_keys("1234")
time.sleep(10)
```

Result:

[image]